# Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'. on another machine

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to deploy my Angular project on AWS S3 but i have this issue when try to `ng build`. However I have this issue only on server, but on local machine everything is fine.

All dependencies are same. I tried to reinstall and update `angular-cli`; remove node modules and clean cache, but nothing happened. How to resolve this issue?

My full error is below:

```
 ERROR in Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
        at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20247:23)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15216:60)
        at visitLazyRoute (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31061:104)
        at AotCompiler.listLazyRoutes (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31029:20)
        at AngularCompilerProgram.listLazyRoutes (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:156:30)
        at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:44:36)
        at AngularCompilerPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:249:66)
        at Promise.resolve.then.then (/srv/www/salesboomerang.com/adminpanel/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:572:50)
        at <anonymous>
```

here my app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { RoutesModule } from './routes/routes.module';
import 'hammerjs';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        CoreModule,
        LayoutModule,
        SharedModule.forRoot(),
        RoutesModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing some changes and compile again . It would compile successfully.
Atleast for me it worked